# Java 8 Stream operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a Stream of Strings called `s`. Is it possible to have a unary operation that converts every lone String to two Strings?

So if the original Stream contains `{a,b,c}` and the operation converts every single String `s` to `s + "1"` and `s + "2"` then we would get: `{a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2}`.

Is this possible (with a lambda expression)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) like

```
stream.flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s + "1", s + "2"));
```

Example:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c")                   // stream of "a", "b", "c"
.flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s + "1", s + "2")) // stream of "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2"
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
c1
c2
```

Comment: Great! This small piece of code does exactly what I was looking for! I never used a flatMap before, so that's why I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this fairly easily using `flatMap`:

```
public Stream<String> multiply(final Stream<String> in, final int multiplier) {
    return in.flatMap(s -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, multiplier).mapToObj(i -> s + i));
}
```

Usage:

```
final Stream<String> test = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
multiply(test, 2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
c1
c2
```